# How to draw single Pixel lines with d3.js / SVG

Tags: svg, d3.js

I want to draw vertical and horizontal lines with exactly one pixel width and an exactly defined color.
Whatever I am trying I can not make one solution work in Firefox, Chrome and Internet Explorer at once correctly.

Say I want to draw a black full horizontal line in the second pixel line, in d3.js you'd think this is the solution:

```js
.append("line")
.attr("x1", 0)
.attr("y1", 1.5)
.attr("x2", 100)
.attr("y2", 1.5)
.attr("stroke-width", 0.5)
.attr("stroke", "black");
```

Mathematically it should do exactly what I want, no?
Nope, it doesn't.
Firefox doesn't display it, IE and Chrome make it grey/transparent.
Not using a +0.5 offset for the y value doesn't help, anything with stroke-width 1 doesn't help either. Each browser does have one exact solution, but there is none that is right with all three.
If that isn't enough you can even add the shape-rendering attribute to the equation, which too doesn't help.
Is there any one size fits all solution for those three browser or do I seriously have to modify the line creation depending on browser?

Answer (score 4):

It's due to anti aliasing, and it's known that some browsers apply it to lines that run along the .5 of the pixel and others do it on the whole pixel.

svg elements have a css prop to override this.

```
shape-rendering: crispEdges
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/shape-rendering

Comment: Adding crisedges makes the line invisible on FF, grey on IE and correct on Chrome. That isn't it...

Comment: try to set the stroke 1 px instead of 0.5 if you use crispEdges